# Bash, Keys, & rSync

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sh, rsync

I have a script here that I have made that I am attempting to convert to using keys, however I am having some issues. The script works beautifully when a passphrase is not specified for the keys, however I want to have a different passphrase for each key on each server. However I am having a bit of an issue accomplishing this with expect command. I have copied the original script below. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

SERVERS="REMOTESERVER1 REMOTESERVER2"
KEYS="SECRET_KEY1 SECRET_KEY2"
MAILTO="EMAIL_TO"
HOSTNAME="$(hostname)"
MSG=""
ERROR=0
DIRERR=0

MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Starting Backup Engine"
for server in $SERVERS; do

    MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Starting backup on $server"

    #Check for backup directory for listed servers. Create if does not exists.
    MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Checking backup folder structure"
    if [ ! -d "/backup/${server}" ]; then
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) /backup/${server} does not exist... creating"
        mkdir -p /backup/$server
        DIRMKD="${DIRMKD}\n$(date) /backup/${server}"
        DIRERR=1
    fi

    #Check for accounts directory in the server backup folder.
    if [ ! -d "/backup/${server}/accounts" ]; then
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) /backup/${server}/accounts does not exist... creating"
        mkdir -p /backup/$server
        DIRMKD="${DIRMKD}\n$(date) /backup/${server}/accounts"
        DIRERR=1
    fi

    #Check for dnszones folder in the server backup folder.
    if [ ! -d "/backup/${server}/dnszones" ]; then
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) /backup/${server}/dnszones does not exist... creating"
        mkdir -p /backup/$server/dnszones
        DIRMKD="${DIRMKD}\n$(date) /backup/${server}/dnszones"
        DIRERR=1
    fi

    #Check for syslogs folder in the server backup folder.
    if [ ! -d "/backup/${server}/syslogs" ]; then
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) /backup/${server}/syslogs does not exist... creating"
        mkdir -p /backup/$server/syslogs
        DIRMKD="${DIRMKD}\n$(date) /backup/${server}/syslogs"
        DIRERR=1
    fi

    #Check for syslogs/apache folder in the server backup folder.
    if [ ! -d "/backup/${server}/syslogs/apache" ]; then
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) /backup/${server}/syslogs/apache does not exist... creating"
        mkdir -p /backup/$server/syslogs/apache
        DIRMKD="${DIRMKD}\n$(date) /backup/${server}/syslogs/apache"
        DIRERR=1
    fi

    #Check for syslogs/apache/domlogs folder in the server backup folder.
    if [ ! -d "/backup/${server}/syslogs/cpanel" ]; then
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) /backup/${server}/syslogs/cpanel does not exist... creating"
        mkdir -p /backup/$server/syslogs/cpanel
        DIRMKD="${DIRMKD}\n$(date) /backup/${server}/syslogs/cpanel"
        DIRERR=1
    fi

    #Check for syslogs/apache/domlogs folder in the server backup folder.
    if [ ! -d "/backup/${server}/syslogs/apache/domlogs" ]; then
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) /backup/${server}/syslogs/apache/domlogs does not exist... creating"
        mkdir -p /backup/$server/syslogs/apache/domlogs
        DIRMKD="${DIRMKD}\n$(date) /backup/${server}/syslogs/apache/domlogs"
        DIRERR=1
    fi

    if [ $DIRERR -eq 0 ]; then
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Backup folder check complete"
    else
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Created new directories:${DIRMKD}"
    fi

    MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Backing up DNS Records"
    rdiff-backup --force --tempdir=/home/tmp --remote-schema "ssh -C -p22 %s rdiff-backup --server" root@$server::/var/named/* /backup/$server/dnszones/
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Could not complete DNS Zone backups for ${server}"
        ERROR=1
        continue
    else
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) DNS Zones have been backed up"
    fi

    MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Backing up server logs"
    #Backup /var/logs/*
    rdiff-backup --force --tempdir=/home/tmp --remote-schema "ssh -C -p22 %s rdiff-backup --server" root@$server::/var/log/* /backup/$server/syslogs/
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Could not complete server log backups for ${server}"
        ERROR=1
        continue
    else
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Server logs have been backed up"
    fi

    MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Backing up Apache logs"
    #Backup /usr/local/apache/logs/*
    rdiff-backup --force --tempdir=/home/tmp --remote-schema "ssh -C -p22 %s rdiff-backup --server" root@$server::/usr/local/apache/logs/* /backup/$server/syslogs/apache
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Could not complete Apache log backups for ${server}"
        ERROR=1
        continue
    else
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Apaceh logs have been backed up"
    fi

    MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Backing up Apache Domlogs"
    #Backup /usr/local/apache/domlogs/*
    rdiff-backup --force --tempdir=/home/tmp --remote-schema "ssh -C -p22 %s rdiff-backup --server" root@$server::/usr/local/apache/domlogs/* /backup/$server/syslogs/apache/domlogs
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Could not complete Apache Domlog backups for ${server}"
        ERROR=1
        continue
    else
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Apache Domlogs have been backed up"
    fi

    MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Backing up cPanel logs"
    #Backup /usr/local/cpanel/logs/*
    rdiff-backup --force --tempdir=/home/tmp --remote-schema "ssh -C -p22 %s rdiff-backup --server" root@$server::/usr/local/cpanel/logs/* /backup/$server/syslogs/cpanel
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Could not complete cPanel log backups for ${server}"
        ERROR=1
        continue
    else
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) CPanel logs have been backed up"
    fi

    MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Backing up accounts"
    #Backup /backup/cpbackup/daily/*
    rdiff-backup --tempdir=/home/tmp --remote-schema "ssh -C -p22 %s rdiff-backup --server" root@$server::/backup/cpbackup/daily/* /backup/$server/accounts
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Could not complete account backups for ${server}"
        ERROR=1
        continue
    else
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Accounts have been backed up"
    fi

    MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Backup for ${server} completed"

    #Delete anything older than one week from accounts while retaining server logs and DNS Zones.
    MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Removing old files from account backups"
    rdiff-backup --force --remove-older-than 7D /backup/$server/accounts/*
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Could not remove old account backups"
        ERROR=1
    fi

done

MSG="${MSG}\n$(date) Backups complete"


if [ $ERROR -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -e "From: root@${HOSTNAME}\nTo: ${MAILTO}\nSubject: Backups completed on ${HOSTNAME}\nDifferential backups completed successfully on ${HOSTNAME} at $(date)\n\n ${MSG}\n\n Available backups:\n$(for server in $SERVERS; do echo -e "\n\n$server:"; rdiff-backup -l /backup/$server/ ; done )" | /usr/sbin/sendmail ${MAILTO}
else
    echo -e "From: root@${HOSTNAME}\nTo: ${MAILTO}\nSubject: Failed backup on ${HOSTNAME}\n${MSG}" | /usr/sbin/sendmail ${MAILTO}
fi
```

Comment: 2 options that I know: a `ssh-agent`, or opening the SSH connections beforehand when you can add the pass phrases with `ControlMaster`.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr

You want to use `ssh-agent`, and `ssh-add` each key that you need. Don't add a passphrase to a key if you're just going to hardcode it in some script, that totally defeats the purpose.